# Update an existing table using selected records in tsql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update, recordset

I am stuck with a query where I need to update an existing table using a dynamically generated record set. I tried searching for the answers but didn't get much help from them.

Here is my query:

```
with t as
(
    SELECT R.Col1, R.Col2, O.Column2, row_number() 
        OVER (partition by R.Col3, R.Col4 
              ORDER BY
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'NA' then R.Col1 END ASC,
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'ND' then R.Col1 END DESC,
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'CA' then R.Col2 END ASC,
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'CD' then R.Col1 END DESC
             ) as NewOrder 
               From RecordsTable R innerjoin OtherTable O on R.Col2 = O.Column1
               where R.Col3 = @Col5Val
)
Update RecordsTable Set RecordsTable.Ordering = t.NewOrder 
       where RecordsTable.Name = t.Col1 
       and RecordsTable.Address = t.Col2
```

The error I am getting is `The multi-part identifier "t.Col1" could not be bound` and `The multi-part identifier "t.Col2" could not be bound`

I am not sure if the query is correct or not, but I guess this should be correct to some extent.

**Table Structures**

`RecordsTable`

```
Col1   |    Col2    |    Col3    |    Col4   |   Ordering
------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    |   78945    |    8345    |    XYZ    |    1
```

`OtherTable`

```
Column1  | Column2    |    Column3    
-----------------------------------
FOO      |   BAR      |    8345
```

**NOTE**
The `cases` are required to sort the records as the `NewOrder` generated from this is required to update the `RecordsTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating one of the tables involved in your CTE, but you aren't linking it to the CTE during your update. Therefore, you need to join the source table back to the CTE using an inner join in your update statement like so:

```
--CTE here

 Update RecordsTable 
 Set RecordsTable.Ordering = t.NewOrder
 from recordstable r
 inner join t on
 r.Name = t.Col1 and r.Address = t.Col2
```

Alternatively, you can include the Name, Address and Ordering columns in your CTE, and directly update the CTE like so:

```
    with t as
(
    SELECT R.Col1, R.Col2, O.Column2, R.Name, R.Address, R.Ordering, row_number() 
        OVER (partition by R.Col3, R.Col4 
              ORDER BY
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'NA' then R.Col1 END ASC,
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'ND' then R.Col1 END DESC,
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'CA' then R.Col2 END ASC,
              CASE WHEN @Criteria = 'CD' then R.Col1 END DESC
             ) as NewOrder 
               From RecordsTable R innerjoin OtherTable O on R.Col2 = O.Column1
               where R.Col3 = @Col5Val
)
Update t
Set t.Ordering = t.NewOrder 
where t.Name = t.Col1 
and t.Address = t.Col2
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EGB50891)